# PhaseScriptExecution 'FBReactNativeSpec error code65 (iOS - React-native)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I've recently upgraded my some packages which broke the code. While generating iOS build I'm getting the error highlighted below.
**(in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods') (1 failure) ##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65**

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.1.1",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.7",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^12.7.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.7.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^12.7.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.14",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.1.2",
    "@ui-kitten/eva-icons": "^5.1.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "query-string": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.65.1",
    "react-native-app-auth": "^6.4.3",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.3.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-offline": "^6.0.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.8.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-pack": "^0.1.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "reselect": "^4.1.7",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "victory-native": "^36.6.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.15.3",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^5.4.1",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^11.5.2",
    "babel-jest": "^29.4.3",
    "eslint": "^8.34.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.0",
    "jest": "^29.4.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.75.0",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.71.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0"
  },
```

Solutions tried which didn't work.

1. arch -x86_64 pod install instead of pod install
2. pod deintegrate > pod cache clean --all > pod install
3. rm -rf node_modules && yarn > npm i > cd ios > pod install

Earlier it just worked based on "npm run ios"

Answer (score 0):

Switch from node 16 to 18 solve the problem for me :)